# Python on Windows Phone?

Tags: .net, python, windows-phone-7

Can I execute Python on Windows Phone? I have heard about IronPython but is it the way to go when I need to compile to a lot of existing Python code for Windows Mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only (some) mananged .net languages are supported on Windows Phone (note. this is not the same as Windows Mobile).
IronPython is the only option available to you when it comes to executing python code on the phone.